# Working with past 2 months (date)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to delete the past 2 months in my database.

I'm saving things in my database like this format `date("n-Y");` zo the output would be `8-2013`

Now i'm trying to delete the past 2 months like this:

Code:

```
echo "<h2>Opruimen.</h2>";

$AFGELOPENMAAND = date("n-Y",strtotime("-1 Months"));
$AFGELOPENMAAND2 = date("n-Y",strtotime("-2 Months"));

$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE geupload = $AFGELOPENMAAND OR geupload = $AFGELOPENMAAND2");
$result->execute();
$hoeveel = $result->rowCount();

if($hoeveel != 0){
    foreach($result as $row){
        unlink($row["thumb"]);
        unlink($row["location"]);

        $resultDEL = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM photos WHERE id = :id');
        $resultDEL->execute(array(':id' => $row["id"]));

        echo 'De vorige 2 maanden zijn verwijdert.';
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL=admin.php">';  
    }
}else{
    echo 'Deze actie is al uitgevoerd of het is niet nodig!!';
}
```

But i can see with my else, if he found something or not. And it doesn't find rows in my database, but there are some with the past 2 months in it.

Am i doing something wrong with my query ?

Grz

Comment: Put ur table structure please

Comment: You can see it here: [link](http://i39.tinypic.com/2up44f7.png)

Comment: Always use single quotes to match the string values. Its not working as u did not used single quotes '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE geupload = $AFGELOPENMAAND OR geupload = $AFGELOPENMAAND2");
$result->execute();
```

with this

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE geupload = '".$AFGELOPENMAAND."' OR  geupload = '".$AFGELOPENMAAND2."'");
$result->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to quote the string you search for in mysql, currently you are searching for month_value-year_value, a negative int

Comment: Aw, nice find! I'd never think of storing dates as strings... I didn't even think of quotes being the core of the problem - in a problem involving dates...

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues...

Prepared statements don't have to be prepared for each iteration when the bound data changes:

```
if($hoeveel != 0){
    $resultDEL = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM photos WHERE id = :id'); //put it here
    foreach($result as $row){
        unlink($row["thumb"]);
        unlink($row["location"]);

        $resultDEL->execute(array(':id' => $row["id"]));

        echo 'De vorige 2 maanden zijn verwijdert.';
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL=admin.php">';  
    }
}else{
   echo 'Deze actie is al uitgevoerd of het is niet nodig!!';
}
```

**However** You could also delete them directly:

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM photos WHERE geupload = $AFGELOPENMAAND OR geupload = $AFGELOPENMAAND2");
$result->execute();
```

**Rule of thumb**: When you read something from DB, and have to process each line so that there is a resulting DB query, 99 out of 100 cases you could have done it entirely in the DB, saving a lot of bandwidth and time.

**EDIT** AdrianBR found the problem... Don't store dates as strings. DB systems are good at handling their own defined datatypes, use them.

Answer (score 0):

My advice, change your "geupload" field to a DATETIME (or DATE) field instead of VARCHAR, it's much much easier to work with and the database can handle this field like a real date instead of a string (like mentioned before).

You can remove the rows, older then two months like this then:

```
DELETE FROM photos WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, geupload, NOW()) > 2
```

You can easily insert or update the current time into this field like this:

```
INSERT INTO photos (.., .., geupload) VALUES (.., .., NOW())

UPDATE photos SET geupload = NOW()
```